# Activator.GetObject returns Authentication failure

Tags: c#, remoting

I have a pair of old (2008) C# applications, one which provides a TCP listener service, and the other which is a client connecting to that service.
If I run both apps on the same machine, it works fine.
But if I try connecting from the client on a machine that is connected only by VPN to the server, then I get Authentication Failure.
Firewalls are off on both machines.

```
IFoo factory = (IFoo)Activator.GetObject(
                    typeof(IFoo),
                    pathtoService);
remoteData = factory.CreateInstance();
```

The CreateInstance call fails with the authentication message.

First - is this old technology replaced by something better (even more simple?)
Second - is there any way to pass credentials so that this will work?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This looks like .NET Remoting. If so, then, yes, you should replace it with WCF.